# Align multiline equations at equality sign

Tags: align, line-breaking, amsmath

I have several (well in this case 2) equations, that I want to align at the equality sign. This is easily done using the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package. Additionally, I want to have a note to the far right of each equation, which I do with double ampersands (`&&`).

My problem is now, what do I do if any of the above-mentioned equations are longer than a single line, i.e. have to be broken up? Right now I have broken them into several environments, but that looks ugly, and not aligned. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I was apparently so hungry that I forgot the MLE, so here it is.

```
\begin{align*}
Y_{i,k}^{-} = Y_{i-1,k} + &g^0_{k}(Y_{i-1}) \Delta_{i-1,k} + \sum_{j=1}^{d} g^1_{k,j}(Y_{i-1}) \Delta W_{i-1,j} \\&+ \sum_{j_1,j_2=1}^d h_{k,j_1,j_2}(Y_{i-1})(\Delta W_{i-1,j_1}\Delta W_{i-1,j_2}-\Omega_{j_1,j_2}\Delta - A_{i-1,j,k}) && (\mbox{Milstein})
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
Y_{i,k} &= \begin{cases}
Y_{i,k}^- & \mbox{if } t_{i} \notin \mathcal{I}^k_{arrival} \\
Y_{i,k}^- + Y_{i,k}^- \Delta J_{i,k} & \mbox{if } t_{i} \in \mathcal{I}^k_{arrival} 
\end{cases} && (\mbox{Jump})
\end{align*}
```

Comment: There are several ways.  If you provide a minimum working example, the "best" way may make itself more apparent for your particular cases.  A lot may depend on how you want the multi-line part of the equations to be aligned.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. It is now included.

Comment: An MWE is more than a code snippet.  For example, I have no idea how `\W` is defined with just a code snippet...or is that just a typo?

Comment: Maybe `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
Y_{i,k}^{-} ={}& Y_{i-1,k} + g^0_{k}(Y_{i-1}) \Delta_{i-1,k} + \sum_{j=1}^{d} g^1_{k,j}(Y_{i-1}) \Delta W_{i-1,j} \\&+ \sum_{j_1,j_2=1}^d h_{k,j_1,j_2}(Y_{i-1})(\Delta W_{i-1,j_1}\Delta W_{i-1,j_2}-\Omega_{j_1,j_2}\Delta - A_{i-1,j,k}) && (\mbox{Milstein})
\\
Y_{i,k} ={}& \begin{cases}
Y_{i,k}^- & \mbox{if } t_{i} \notin \mathcal{I}^k_{arrival} \\
Y_{i,k}^- + Y_{i,k}^- \Delta J_{i,k} & \mbox{if } t_{i} \in \mathcal{I}^k_{arrival} 
\end{cases} && (\mbox{Jump})
\end{align*}
\end{document}`

Comment: `\W` was a typo, it was supposed to just be `W`.

Answer (score 1):

I propose two solutions for the first equation, using  `\tag`. or the second equation, you'll a really centred equationusing `\rlap`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   & \begin{split}Y_{i,k}^{-} = Y_{i-1,k}&+g⁰_{k}(Y_{i-1}) \Delta_{i-1,k} + ∑_{j=1}^{d} g¹_{k,j}(Y_{i-1}) ΔW_{i-1,j} \\[-1.5ex
    ]&+ \smashoperator{∑_{j₁,j₂=1}^d h_{k,j₁,j₂}}(Y_{i-1})(ΔW_{i-1,j₁}ΔW_{i-1,j₂}-\Omega_{j₁,j₂}Δ- A_{i-1,j,k}) \end{split} \tag{Milstein}
\end{align*}

\begin{multline*}
  Y_{i,k}^{-} = Y_{i-1,k} + g⁰_{k}(Y_{i-1}) \Delta_{i-1,k} + ∑_{j=1}^{d} g¹_{k,j}(Y_{i-1}) ΔW_{i-1,j} \\[-1.5ex]
  + \smashoperator{∑_{j₁,j₂=1}^d h_{k,j₁,j₂}}(Y_{i-1})(ΔW_{i-1,j₁}ΔW_{i-1,j₂}-\Omega_{j₁,j₂}Δ- A_{i-1,j,k}) \tag{Milstein}
\end{multline*}

\begin{align*}
& & Y_{i,k} & = \begin{cases}
    Y_{i,k}^- & \mbox{if } t_{i} ∉ \mathcal{I}^k_\mathrm{arrival} \\
    Y_{i,k}^- + Y_{i,k}^- ΔJ_{i,k} & \mbox{if } t_{i} ∈ \mathcal{I}^k_\mathrm{arrival}
  \end{cases} & & \rlap{(Jump)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]